# PWM understanding

Tags: pwm

I am giving PWM to a MOSFET (50% duty). It switches about 8.5V to be fed to a phase of a motor. There are 3 such phases.

Now, I am looking at voltage measured from these phases as well. I have 3KΩ and 10KΩ resistors acting as a voltage divider which steps down the voltage to about 1.96V. This will be measured by the ADC.

Now, will the value of 1.96V vary with respect to the PWM duty cycle? Will this voltage be lower at lower duty cycles and so on and so forth?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a 3K" or "10K". In this case it's so bad that one has to decipher and guess what you mean. Not only are the units missing, but you haven't even said what physical thing they are supposed to apply to. We don't tolerate such gross sloppiness here. -1

Comment: Sorry sir. I have a voltage divider of 3K ohms and 10K ohms. Thesy are a part of a voltage divider from the motor phase voltage (8.5V) to a 3.3V ttl pin (of a micro controller).I also have a LPF filter here ( common LPF for adc measurement).

Comment: @Vinod I'll revise the question for you to be more specific. Lesson to learn: Don't assume anything in engineering, and don't leave out details for others to misinterpret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `duty cycle` of the signal effectively gives the percent of the amplitude that will be seen by the circuit having it applied. That is,

V = Vo*D

Where D is the duty cycle.

This can seen as very intuitive if you consider the definition of duty cycle. Namely, the signal is ON (HIGH) for what percent of the time? For a duty cycle of 50% we have that *half* of the time the output is high and *half* of the time the output is low. So if you *average* this then we have

Vo = (V + 0)/2 = V/2

Or for a duty cycle of 25% we have:

Vo = (V + 0 + 0 + 0)/4 = V/4

Comment: Hello Sir,
Thank you. I understand your point. The formula you give applies to an average value of the voltage. Say, we have 50% duty cycle for a duration of 10msecs. The supply being 5V. Then the average voltage is 2.5V for that specific duration. I am interested in the instantaneous voltage. That would be 5V for 5msecs and 0V for the remainder 5msecs. Right.

Comment: Yes Vinod, you are right. You put 5V or 0V into your voltage divider, and in your case 1.96V or 0V will come out. That voltage will still depend on your duty cycle.

Comment: @VinodKaruvat, instantanously voltage is going to be the amplitude of the signal for whatever duration its state is *high* followed by zero for the remaining period `(Period - highTime)`. The period has no consequence on the average voltage because your signal is periodic.